# How to handle shared resource in PHP scripts

Tags: php

Please excuse if it is too basic a question in PHP. 
I am a desktop app developer so not sure about it,

Just like we put lock, synchronize or use critical sections in different languages to access some common resource by multiple threads. Is my assumption true that if a script (php) is accessed by several different clients simultaneously would be processed in multiple threads ? and if they are updating a common record they would need some synchronization ?

How is it done in Php ?

In my case a PHP page may have multiple android clients accessing it and possibly modifying/accessing same record or table row(s).

Comment: What is "a record" in your case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP is explicitly single-threaded and each call to a PHP script will be handled by its own server thread / process.

Updating records simultaneously has to be handled by the underlying database layer. MySQL for example is widely used and thread safe. When using transactions, you can guarantee also other levels of atomicity.

Comment: Stored procedures are not atomic by themself. Sure you didn't mean something else (e.g. transactions)?

Answer (score 2):

When using a DBMS (what you do), then that one is responsible for data consistency. Especially when reading there is no problem anyway, because problems can only occur, when something gets modified. If you are unsure, use transactions when writing.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about accessing a server, then it depends on the server whether it's threaded (Apache is not, nginx is, etc.) and that has nothing to do with PHP itself (which is not threaded).

Either way, if you're talking about MySQL, then it's a different story because MySQL works per-connection session (things like `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `LAST_INSERT_ID()` depend on the connection, not the database as a whole).  So if you have something like this:

```
//some insert query
$stmt->execute();
$id = $connection->insert_id;
$stmt2->execute($id);
```

...it is "safe" in that even if the first `stmt` is executed many times before a single `stmt2` gets executed, the ID will still be correct because the connection is the same.

Comment: Thanks, server is apache in my case, are you suggesting since it's apache it would block/refuse other clients while first one is being processed ?

Comment: @Ahmed no, not at all; Apache spawns multiple child processes and can run out of slots and *then* it will refuse connections, but I doubt you will run out.  (**NOTE:** there is an implementation of apache that uses threads).